# Get Country from Textbox.Text IP

Tags: regex, vb.net, ip

I made a IP changer from loaded location from PC and show in TextBox.Text and I made 2 Labels (countryLbl and ipLbl) to display Country and IP as well.
Well I tried few regex or webclient, but I get everytime error or authentication failed, so seems to me that website protect or I cant explain why, it is looking really easy and simple.
I deleted all regex as it was not working so I will not post anything here and I have really killed all day by looking, still not successful.

Comment: You don't put tags in the question title. Also, he corrected your misspelled words and grammatical errors, as expected. Please show some gratitude and respect.

Comment: @jeremy calm down and don't worry, your question makes the same sense with or without the edit: none.